# apply joint effort service call doesn't do much in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a ros node that connects to my gazebo model. It makes a service call to rotate the joints (wheels). If I perform the ros service call from the cmd line I am able to see the wheels move. However, from the cpp node, it doesn't seem to move. Here is my cpp code:

```
gazebo_msgs::ApplyJointEffort r; 
    r.request.duration = ros::Duration(2.);
    r.request.joint_name = "right_wheel_hinge";
ros::ServiceClient client2 = gazebo.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::ApplyJointEffort>("/gazebo/apply_joint_effort"); client2.call(r);
```

I have this in my main function of my cpp file. I am starting with Gazebo, so your help is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200735/apply-joint-effort-service-call-doesn%27t-do-much-in-gazebo/) by [Bardia](https://answers.ros.org/users/21105/bardia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
gazebo_msgs::ApplyJointEffort r; 
r.request.duration = ros::Duration(2.);
r.request.joint_name = "right_wheel_hinge";
...
```

This may just be a copy/paste mistake, but are you setting the `effort` field of the `ApplyJointEffort` msg?

If you don't set it, it will initialise to 0, which could be an explanation for what you are seeing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1